# Partition problem when upgrading to 13.10

Tags: partitioning

I am currently upgrading my ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10 with the distribution upgrade app. How can I reduce my partition size to make more space for my windows partition?

Comment: gparted: `sudo apt-get install gparted` partition manager

Answer (score 0):

You need a LiveUSB or LiveCD, preferably GParted. Get it from

```
gparted.org/download.php
```

Use Tuxboot to make a bootable USB Pendrive and boot from the USB. If pendrive with Tuxboot installed GParted fails to boot (happened to me), use UNetBootin. When you boot into GParted, click on the drive with Windows partition and click Resize/Move. Resize the partition as you want and click Apply. It will start going, it's a fast process. When you're done, reboot, and this time boot into your hard drive. Done! You're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu live CDs come with GParted pre-installed so just boot from a Live CD/USB and resize your partitions that way.